# Git - I added a repository with "git init", now I want to remove it

Tags: git, github

I thought "git rm" or "rm git" would work. What am I missing or what should I change? The course is looking for a simple answer[image: Question course is asking in picture]

Comment: `git init` does **not** add a file, but initialize an empty index in the given folder.

Comment: what would the code look like if I typed that out?

Comment: `rm -rf .git/` should do

Comment: That worked @TimCastelijns Thank you!

Comment: Notice, that although @TimCastelijns instructions are the right way to "undo" a `git init`, you should never ever `rm -rf` anything that anyone on the internet says without knowing what you're doing. If you want to understand what I mean, do a `rm -rf ~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the following:

`sudo rm -rf .git/`

Run the above command in the directory where you have initialized the git.

Comment: sudo should not be necessary if the user has permission to delete the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the ".git" folder that is create after the `git init`.

This folder is usually hidden and created in the root of your directory.

Comment: Notice that the property of being "hidden" is merely the fact that the name starts with `.`, on unixoid systems.